# Getting specific numbers out of array

Tags: python, arrays

So this is my array:

```
field = [[1, 2, 4, 4],
         [4, 1, 4, 2],
         [2, 1, 4, 3],
         [2, 4, 2, 3],
         [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

and if i have following coordinates:

```
co= [(0, 1),
     (1, 1),
     (2, 1)]
```

In this case my new array should look like:

```
[[1, 4, 4],
 [4, 4, 2],
 [2, 4, 3],
 [2, 4, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

anyone has any idea how ? I have managed to get just numbers that have to be deleted but its not what i want..
Note: It has to be made for field array of x length and same with coordinates.

Thanks for help!

Comment: `for (x, y) in co: del field[x][y]` (that would be python)

Comment: What exactly do the coordinates do?  Specifically, what is the second number in the coordinate doing?

Comment: for (x, y) in co:
 del field[x][y]
print(field)

Gives :
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: first number gives which row it is and the 2nd one is which column in that row
So if it is 0,1
the number would be 2

Comment: @njzk2, only need to add reverse-sort and it's perfect :)

Comment: @user3311120: no it does not. I have tested this code and it give the expected output. (unless your input is different?)

Comment: @njzk2 A general solution for this problem should probably consider a list of coordinates with two in the same sub-list, I would expect this to create problems if `(0, 3)` would be deleted before `(0,1)`...

Comment: @ReutSharabani : indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
for c in sorted(co, reverse=True):
    field[c[0]].pop(c[1])
```

Or as @njzk2 suggested:

```
for (x, y) in sorted(co, reverse=True): del field[x][y]
```

Simply access the `field` list-of-lists in index `c[0]`, which indicates what list is to be accessed.

Then pop the element from the sub-list in index `c[1]`.

Result is now in `field`.

**Note:** I sort them in reversed order for the case you'll remove from the same list, so indices for previous elements don't change. For instance: `(0, 3)` should pop before `(0, 1)`.